# how to read messages with the session id from session-based queue using Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I have Azure Logic App that processes messages from Service Bus session-based queue using **When one or more messages arrive in a queue (peek-lock)** connector.

I have sent 20 messages into Service Bus queue with the same session id.

But it is not reading all messages at once. It is reading one by one.

I have followed these links

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#when-one-or-more-messages-arrive-in-a-queue-(peek-lock)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#when-a-message-is-received-in-a-queue-(peek-lock)

Can anyone suggest me how to read messages with the session id from session-based queue using Azure Logic App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Please click `···` in the upper right corner of the `When one or more messages arrive in a queue (peek-lock)` trigger, then click `setting`:
[image]

Turn off `Split on`:

[image]

In this way, messages with the same `sessionId` can be read at the same time:

[image]

**Explanation:**

Enabling `Split On` will create a workflow instance for each message.

Comment: One question, whether we need to close the session inside the foreach or outside the foreach. if outside the foreach, then how to use sessionid?

Comment: Hi, @Pradeep. If there are multiple messages, you need to close the session in `for each`. I tested it. If you select `Close a session in a queue` action outside, it will automatically add `for each`.

Comment: Yes, But basically we need to close the session after reading  all messages

Comment: Currently I'm using variable inside foreach loop to get session id and then using that custom variable outside of the foreach loop while closing the session in queue.